# Solving inequality in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I have to graphically represent the following subset in the complex plane being z a complex number:
$A={1<|z|<2}$

However after trying to do it on WolframAlpha it says that "inequalities are not well difined in the complex plane".

What I did previously was solve it like it was a regular inequality system in the real numbers, resulting in $b<-a+4$ and $b>-a+1$

How can I solve this?

Comment: This would be the shaded region between the circles $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: Remember that the modulus of a complex number is just its distance from the pole.

Comment: I get it now, thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 1):

The geometric interpretation of this would be an open annulus centred at $0$ with inner radius $1$ and outer radius $2$.

To see this, observe that $|z|$ represents the Euclidean distance from $z$ to $0$. The condition $1 < |z|$ restricts $z$ to be outside of the unit disk, and similarly for $|z| < 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|z|$ is the distance from $z$ to $0$.  So geometrically, $1 < |z| < 2$ is the region inside ... and outside ...